# iterate through folders - how to do this?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the about 50 folder names and I want to run this command against them:

```
Icacls “foldername” /reset /c /t
```

Do you know how I can do this via a batch file? The end user just wants to double click it and it goes off and runs through each folder.

I suppose I need a text file with the folder names on each line?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not clear if you want to run the command against all or just some of the folders.

In case you want to run the command against all of the folders in a given folder, read `HELP FOR` and try this in the command line

```
FOR /d %d in (*.*) do @echo Icacls %d /reset /c /t
```

change `%d` to `%%d` to include it in a batch file, test extensively, finally remove the `ECHO`

In case you want to run against a list of folders, then try

```
FOR /f %d "tokens=*" in (myfolderslist.txt) do @echo Icacls "%d" /reset /c /t
```

Comment: thanks for that - I wanted solution 2 but I get an error:The syntax of the command is incorrect.

D:\apps\solution\tmp>FOR /f d" /reset /c /t

I did exactly as solution 2 and I have a text file called myfolderslist that lists fodlers in the format of:

"d:\apps\solution\tmp\new folder 1"
"d:\apps\solution\tmp\new folder 2"
"d:\apps\solution\tmp\new folder 3"

Any ideas?

Comment: can't read your comment. Please edit your original post with the actual content of the file and the complete comand line.

Comment: figured it out (user error!) - one question, I had to remove the "tocken=*" - what does this do and do I need this?

Comment: First, it is not `"tocken=*"` it's `"tokens=*"`. And second, yes, you need it, it will make it work for the cases your folders have spaces in the name.